# DB2 count(*) over(partition by fieldname) giving -104 z/OS version 7

Tags: sql, db2, window-functions

I have slimmed down the query to remove potential complications, in addition I have verified that the fields are correct. DB2 UDB zSeries V7 is my db2 version.

```
SELECT 
    STDINSTRCD, 
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY STDINSTRCD),
    CAST(STDINSTRDESC AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS INSTR,
    C.STDINSTRSEQ,
    1
FROM 
    SYST.SCC004 C
WHERE  
    C.STDINSTRCD = '098'
```

I have tried a subquery as well.

```
select 
 H2.FRSTSTDINSTRCD,
 (select count(*) from SYST.scC004 Ci where '098'=Ci.STDINSTRCD) as cnt, 
 cast(STDINSTRDESC as varchar(1000)),
 C.STDINSTRSEQ,
 1
from SYST.scE4A00 H2
 LEFT OUTER JOIN SYST.scC004 C
 ON C.STDINSTRCD = H2.FRSTSTDINSTRCD
 WHERE
  H2.CTLENTYID='MCS'
  AND H2.VCKVAL='12654'
  AND H2.POKVAL='0198617S12 000  000'
```

The error is receive is om.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: (;, FROM INTO [sqlcode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_return_codes) [sqlstate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0sttmsg.htm)
-104 Illegal Symbol token.
42601 A character, token, or clause is invalid or missing.

Any advice? I have been unable to determine what syntax error I might me making.

Comment: Are you sure that version supports window functions? V7 is really, really old (the oldest version for which a manual is still available is V8 and I can't find any reference to window functions there)

Answer (score 0):

are there any weird special characters in there that might not be printing? 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IY43009 
basically sounds like a weird cr/lf or special char? Any copy pasting from *nix to windows ?

Also, I'm not sure why you need partition by anyway? would a group by not accomplish your goal. (looks like your just counting number of rows that met your criteria)... 
something like this for your first query?

```
SELECT 
 STDINSTRCD, 
 count(1) ,
 CAST(STDINSTRDESC AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS INSTR,
 C.STDINSTRSEQ,
 1
FROM SYST.SCC004 C
WHERE  C.STDINSTRCD = '098'
group by 
STDINSTRCD, 
CAST(STDINSTRDESC AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS INSTR,
C.STDINSTRSEQ,
1
```

Comment: I am not transitioning from unix to windows. I have stayed entirely in windows and removing the lines lets the query run. I will look into the special character issue but as far as I can tell there shouldn't be anything strange going on there.

Comment: which lines did you remove to get it to run? "and removing the lines lets the query run"..

Comment: I am able to recreate the error too on my version of db2 (9.something)
and it seems to be the "count(*) over ( partition by" that is giving me grief, if I change that to use row_number() over() as rownum it will work... would the rownumber function give you similar information as count(*), seems like it would?

Comment: count(*) over(partition by STDINSTRCD),  is the line I mentioned. I'll try row_number

Comment: Row_number had the same issue. Note that I need to avoid grouping by the various fields as I need to use the windowing functions for what I am attempting to do.

Comment: If you just want counts w/out group by try this .. I wonder if the error is a UDB driver thing? We have a similar set up here and I get the same error but not on all aggregate functions.. weird. This article even uses syntax just like yours.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/lyle/0110lyle.html
 
SELECT  STDINSTRCD, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM SYST.SCC004 C2
        WHERE C2.STDINSTRCD = C.STDINSTRCD
     )  AS COUNT, 
    CAST (STDINSTRDESC AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS INSTR, 
    C.STDINSTRSEQ, 
    1
FROM SYST.SCC004 C
WHERE C.STDINSTRCD = '098'

Answer (score 0):

Db2 Version 7 for z/OS does not support OLAP functions, or row_number(). You need to rewrite your query to avoid using such functions. They arrived in later Db2 versions.  See also other people's tips on alternatives via [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013806000).