# DB2 Sql for transpose in Mainframe

Tags: db2, mainframe

[want to achieve below the in mainframe Db2 Sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5WuN.png)

Comment: You need to actually ask a question not post a picture of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Db2 for LUW this will work. Mainframe SQL will be similar. Just use your table name in place of the `TABLE(VALUES ... AS(..)` bit

```
SELECT
     MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Student_no END) AS Student_no_1
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN S_Name     END) AS S_Name_1    
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Marks      END) AS Marks_1
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Student_no END) AS Student_no_2
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN S_Name     END) AS S_Name_2
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Marks      END) AS Marks_2
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Student_no END) AS Student_no_3
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN S_Name     END) AS S_Name_3
,    MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Marks      END) AS Marks_3
FROM
(   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Student_no) AS RN
    ,     Student_no
    ,     S_Name
    ,     Marks
    FROM
        TABLE(VALUES( 2, 'Abc', 89),( 5, 'dfg', 35),( 9, 'qwe', 56))
            AS (Student_no, S_Name, Marks)
)

STUDENT_NO_1 S_NAME_1 MARKS_1 STUDENT_NO_2 S_NAME_2 MARKS_2 STUDENT_NO_3 S_NAME_3 MARKS_3
------------ -------- ------- ------------ -------- ------- ------------ -------- -------
           2 Abc           89            5 dfg           35            9 qwe           56
```

Comment: Thanks, 
I have tried above query, but it's not compatible with My DB2 V11 throwing SQL Code=-4743.  we have an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Which bit did it not like?

Comment: Row_number() function is not accepting

Comment: Have you checked that it is supported in your version of Db2? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322249/db2-count-overpartition-by-fieldname-giving-104-z-os-version-7

Comment: Thanks It helped

Comment: With this same qurrey i have further doubt . What if student number is not defined(if we dont know how many student present)  how we can transpose in that case???   Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to generate the SQL code based on how many students you have, or reconsider the need to transpose the data in SQL..  at some point you would hit the limit on the number of columns allowed in a query.